# How can I send a GET Request with link to a directory outside of www or public_html?

Tags: php, linux, webserver

This is on a live server which I cannot give here but my file structure goes like this.

```
public_html > admin > index.php
resources> config.php and functions.php // this is same the level as web directory
resources > templates > back > delete_items.php
```

I got this link that is supposed to reach delete_items.php with a get request from the admin index.php but when I set the path to go back like this

```
../../resources/templates/back/delete_items.php
```

it does not go back but instead displays

```
mywebsite.com/resources/templates/back/delete_items.php?id=1
```

It works fine with XAMPP.

Comment: Can't you use the absolute URL that you need ?

Comment: No because is in the HOME directory  /home/my_username/public_html, so I have to go back before the root of the website. This is with godaddy by the way.

Comment: Can you post the HTML link element? Or the PHP that generates it?

Comment: <a href="../../resources/templates/back/delete_order.php?id=$order_id>Delete</a>      it takes me to mysite.com/resources/templates/back/delete_order.php?id=62 and of course I get FILE not found in the browser since it's looking for it in the public directory instead of going back to the home directory.